# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, authentication, google-play-services, noclassdeffounderror

I'm new to it, working on my first app and am trying to implement Leaderboard using google play game services (Cloudonce). I've already matched the SHA-1 fingerprint from my keystore and App signing Upload certificate (on play console) with **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs**, which solved my earlier error `error_not_authorised`, but now it gives:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
```

Checked lot of similar posts in last few days, but don't seem to find a solution. Can someone please help me?
I'm using **gradle build**, and the **adb logcat** logs are as follows:

```
04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   : *** [Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/11/20 15:28:11 +02:00 ERROR: Exception launching token request: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount  

04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   :  #0 0x918dc6bc (libunity.so) ? 0x46d6bc  
04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   :  #1 0x91e7ad40 (libunity.so) ? 0xa0bd40  
04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   :  #2 0x91b5c888 (libunity.so) ? 0x6ed888  
04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   :  #3 0x91b5c790 (libunity.so) ? 0x6ed790  
04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   :  
04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   : (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)  
04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   :   
04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   : *** [Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/11/20 15:28:11 +02:00 ERROR: UnityEngine.AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount  

04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   :   at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String methodName, System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) [0x00041] in <6084548bc46840b9ba4aa48ad550def0>:0   

04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   :   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID (System.IntPtr javaClass, System.String methodName, System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) [0x00001] in <6084548bc46840b9ba4aa48ad550def0>:0  

04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   :   at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID[ReturnType] (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String methodName, System.Object[] args, System.Boolean isStatic) [0x00009] in <6084548bc46840b9ba4aa48ad550def0>:0  

04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   :   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID[ReturnType] (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String methodName, System.Object[] args, System.Boolean isStatic) [0x00001] in <6084548bc46840b9ba4aa48ad550def0>:0   

04-11 15:28:11.302   654   723 W Unity   :   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObj
```

Comment: What is your plugin version?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 It's CloudOnce v2.6.8

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 checked deeper. The Cloudonce v2.6.8 uses: 
- GPGS plugin v0.9.64
- Play Services Resolver v1.2.111